# Does Amazon RDS support multiple databases per instance?

Tags: amazon-rds

Title says it all... does it support multiple databases, or do I have to create a new instance for each database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can create multiple databases per instance, see their respective FAQ: [What is a database instance (DB Instance)?](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#2)

> You can think of a DB Instance as a MySQL 5.1 environment in the cloud
>   with the compute and storage resources you specify. You can create and
>   delete DB Instances, define/refine infrastructure attributes of your
>   DB Instance(s), and control access and security via the AWS Management
>   Console, Amazon RDS APIs, and Command Line Tools. Multiple MySQL
>   databases can be created on a given DB Instance.

You can create databases using normal SQL commands, eg:

`CREATE DATABASE <database_name>;`